# SDL2 в проекте Qt5 для Android. В JNI_OnLoad из SDL2 ошибка в FindClass((env, "org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity")): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, qt, sdl2

Пытаюсь подключить библиотеку SDL2 к проекту на Qt5 для Android в Qt Creator.

Сначала собрал в Android Studio SDL2 для Android по инструкциям от http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/52_hello_mobile/android_windows/index.php.

В результате получил библиотеку libSDL2.so и дополнительно тестовый apk (просто закрашивает окно и рисует на нём прямоугольник), который успешно запускается на телефоне.

Затем создал в Qt Creator примитивный проект для Android, который успешно запускается на телефоне (просто показывает окно с меню).

Потом подключил библиотеку libSDL2.so к проекту в Qt Creator и добавил в код

```
#include "SDL.h"
```

И теперь это примитивное Qt+SDL-приложение вылетает с ошибкой в процессе запуска.

Вот лог сообщений:

```
W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
I Qt      : qt started
E SDL     : FindClass(env=0x7185bb5c00, classname=org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity) failed
E SDL     : Failed to register methods of org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI FindClass called with pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.libsdl.app.SDLActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.qtproject.example.test-4jVyhe6pYUnxV4Wpm6BuKg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/org.qtproject.example.test-4jVyhe6pYUnxV4Wpm6BuKg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/org.qtproject.example.test-4jVyhe6pYUnxV4Wpm6BuKg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Class) (Runtime.java:-2)
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader) (Runtime.java:1115)
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void java.lang.Runtime.load0(java.lang.Class, java.lang.String) (Runtime.java:936)
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void java.lang.System.load(java.lang.String) (System.java:1631)
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtNative$3.run() (QtNative.java:223)
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtThread$2.run() (QtThread.java:88)
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void org.qtproject.qt5.android.QtThread$1.run() (QtThread.java:61)
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]   at void java.lang.Thread.run() (Thread.java:919)
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]     in call to FindClass
F ct.example.tes: java_vm_ext.cc:577]     from java.lang.String java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.Class)
```

А вот исходный код функции JNI_OnLoad из файла SDL_android_main.c (из проекта SDL2-2.0.14):

```
static void
register_methods(JNIEnv *env, const char *classname, JNINativeMethod *methods, int nb)
{
    jclass clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, classname);
    if(clazz == NULL)
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "SDL", "FindClass(env=%p, classname=%s) failed", env, classname);
    if (clazz == NULL || (*env)->RegisterNatives(env, clazz, methods, nb) < 0) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "SDL", "Failed to register methods of %s", classname);
        return;
    }
}

/* Library init */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved)
{
    mJavaVM = vm;
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;
  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "SDL", "TRACE: JNI_OnLoad");

    if ((*mJavaVM)->GetEnv(mJavaVM, (void **)&env, JNI_VERSION_1_4) != JNI_OK) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "SDL", "Failed to get JNI Env");
        return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
    }

    register_methods(env, "org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity", SDLActivity_tab, SDL_arraysize(SDLActivity_tab));
    register_methods(env, "org/libsdl/app/SDLInputConnection", SDLInputConnection_tab, SDL_arraysize(SDLInputConnection_tab));
    register_methods(env, "org/libsdl/app/SDLAudioManager", SDLAudioManager_tab, SDL_arraysize(SDLAudioManager_tab));
    register_methods(env, "org/libsdl/app/SDLControllerManager", SDLControllerManager_tab, SDL_arraysize(SDLControllerManager_tab));

    return JNI_VERSION_1_4;
}
```

При вызове FindClass возникает исключение java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. Насколько я понимаю, проблема в том, что при загрузке библиотеки libSDL2.so в проект Qt стандартно вызывается функция JNI_OnLoad, которая должна зарегистрировать функции библиотеки SDL из активити SDLActivity (и прочих по списку). Но FindClass не может найти "org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity".

Почему это происходит?

JNI_OnLoad вызывается не из того места (хотя я сам не понимаю, что может означать "не из того места")? Или это как-то связано с потоками Qt и SDL и именно поэтому не срабатывает FindClass?

Или у меня вообще в Qt-проекте нет этой активити SDLActivity и непонятно, что я ищу? И мне нужно добавить эту активити из библиотеки SDL в проект Qt, но тогда как это сделать? Или мне просто нужно указать где именно искать эту активити, но тоже как это сделать? Эта активити есть в исходных кодах проекта SDL2-2.0.14 в файле SDLActivity.java. После построения из него библиотеки libSDL2.so я вижу функции этой активити внутри библиотеки libSDL2.so в виде, например, Java_org_libsdl_app_SDLActivity_nativePause. Но в classes.dex Qt-приложения у меня нет упоминаний о SDLActivity.

Я пытался убрать функцию JNI_OnLoad из файла SDL_android_main.c и пересобрал заново libSDL2.so без этой функции. А потом в коде Qt-приложения добавил свою реализацию JNI_OnLoad. Но и в моей реализации FindClass не находит org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity.

Comment: В теории вам нужно собрать SDL не в `.so`, а в `.aar` из модуля `android-project`, в котором и есть эти java-классы, либо добавить их исходники в свой проект (не забывая про запись активности в манифест). Только я понятия не имею про Qt-проекты и как к ним подключать зависимости.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. "В теории" aar подключается к Qt-проекту. Напишу что получится.